# Google Directions API return different waypoint_order and legs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a system to trace route using Google Maps API.
I have the points of origin and destination and between these points there are some waypoints.
By tracing the route Google returns me the best route and mark these points on the map.
We display the route data in a div.
My function that calculates the route, the part that returns the data looks like this:

```
directionsService.route(request, $.proxy(function(response, status){
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var orders = response.routes[0].waypoint_order; 
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var total_distance = 0;
      var displayRoute = $('#detail-route');


      for (i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++){

         var routeSegment = i + 1,
         from_address = route.legs[i].start_address.split(','),
         to_address = route.legs[i].end_address.split(',');
         total_distance += Math.floor(route.legs[i].distance.value / 1000);

         displayRoute.append('<b>Trecho ' + routeSegment + ': </b><br/>');
         displayRoute.append('<b>Saindo de: </b>' + from_address[0] + '<br/>');
         displayRoute.append('<b>Indo para: </b>' + to_address[0] + '<br/>');
         displayRoute.append('<b>Distância: </b>' + route.legs[i].distance.text);
      }

  displayRoute.prepend('total:' + this.format(total_distance) + ' km' + '<br/><br/>');
```

function `format()` is my function for format km..

The problem is that, on some routes, the `waypoint_order` shows a different order than the one in `legs`. For example:

For a given route, the `route.legs[i]` returns order: 'waypoint 0, waypoint 1, waypoint 3, waypoint 2', but the  `waypoint_order`attribute returns [3, 0, 2, 1, 3]

Is this the expected behavior, or am i missing something here?

Comment: Is that waypoint_order really `[3, 0, 1, 3]` or is that a typo on your part?  i.e. it's missing waypoint #2?  Or did you mean to type something like `[3, 0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: It was a typo, now corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see you `google.maps.DirectionsRequest` object, please?

Comment: Facing the same problem, attached is a link of how Google plots it vs what I get when I plot it with the waypoint order http://imgur.com/a/p8DdL

Comment: You must not use waypoint_order to render your markers. See my answer, i have a working example.

Answer (score 14):

Is an expected behaivour since:

*If optimizeWaypoints was set to true, this field will contain the re-ordered permutation of the input waypoints. For example, if the input was:
  **Origin:** Los Angeles

  **Waypoints:** Dallas, Bangor, Phoenix
  **Destination:** New York
and the optimized output was ordered as follows:
  **Origin:** Los Angeles
  **Waypoints:** Phoenix, Dallas, Bangor
  **Destination:** New York
then this field will be an Array containing the values [2, 0, 1]. Note that the numbering of waypoints is zero-based.
If any of the input waypoints has stopover set to false, this field will be empty, since route optimization is not available for such queries.*

As stated here: [DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult)

**The waypoint_order is the optimized order**

Comment: Okay, so I did, my problem is that the data are not equal.
The problem is that the waypoint_order returns a different order marked on the map, already optimized.

Comment: Yes, if you want the exact order you pass through, set the `optimizeWaypoints` property of `google.maps.DirectionsRequest` to `false`

Comment: Ok, I want to insert the points where I will go, origin, destination and stops. and I want Google to optimize the route for me. This is already being done, I insert data and Google returns the best order, as optimizeWaypoints is true.
I have a hidden field named order, and his value is inserted according to the ordering of the points' waypoint_order ', only that this order is not equal to the points marked on the map, or with data that my' response.routes [0]. legs .... 'returns.

Comment: could you give an example which is having this behaviour

Comment: My zip code of origin and destination are the same, what changes are my breakpoints between them.
I have a loop to display my routes, is in the code above. "i = 0, i <route.legs.length, i + ..." points marked on the map are displayed in the respective orders in a div, the order that Google returns in waypoints_order is different from the amounts that are marked on the map and div.

Comment: Ok, what are your origin and destination?

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but for actually reproduce the same data I would like to know the actual origin/destination (and waypoints), for exeple: Origin/Destinatin: NewYour, Waypoints: Washington, Chicago,...

Comment: I'm using zip code; Origin: 06763-110 Destination: 06763-110 waypoints: [11015-050, 12010-030, 07917-000, 31110-130] The order that google is returning me is this: [2,3,1,0], but the points are marked on the map: 07917-000, 31110-130, 12010-030, 11015-050 –

Comment: I think I'm facing the same problem as @Vanderson mentioned. The waypoint_order Array is different that what Google is plotting on the map. The plotting on the map is always circular but when I plot markers according to waypoint order, it isn't

Answer (score 4):

Yes as @sabotero point out, it is an expected behaviour, but there is nothing wrong or strange about that.

When optimizeWaypoints is true, google map try to find the best order of waypoints so that the distance be minimal. For example you can add four locations : Athens-NewYork-London-Los Angeles the google map will  find that it is better to go first to London and after to New York. So will return in the array `route.legs` Athens-London-NewYork-Los Angeles and in `waypoint_order` will return [1, 0](is only two because is without origin and destination) to inform you that the original order of locations have change. That means that in the first position(waypoint_order[0]) will be the second(returns 1) location who is London and in the second position(waypoint_order[1]) will be the first location(returns 0) who is New York.

Note here that the origin and destination never change position, you always start from the origin you put and you end up in a destination you put. Thats why in waypoint_order is not appear the origin and the destination . So if you have same markers before the request and want to change the order you must exclude the origin and the destination when you reorder, this two will be in the same position.

Now if you want just to draw the markers from the request, don't use waypoint but route legs.

I had made an example, you can enable or disable the optimize with a checkbox and you can see that always the labels of markers come out with the right order:
http://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/03wtc6jv/

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //first,
    position: route.legs[0].start_location,
    map: map,
    label: (0).toString()
  });
  for (var i = 1; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: route.legs[i].start_location,
    map: map,
    label: i.toString()
    });
  }
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //last one
   position: route.legs[route.legs.length - 1].end_location,
   map: map,
   label: route.legs.length.toString()
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a full working day on this, I finally figured out the mistake that I was making and it wasn't from the Google library.

I had to place the 1st marker by myself and then follow the `waypoint_order` because the `Array` that is supplied by `waypoint_order` is for the waypoints which exclude the first/initial/origin position marker.

What I did was take my existing `Array` of marker object and shift the first one and then sort the `Array` according to the order given in `waypoint_order` and then unshift() the first marker back to the markers Array. Unfortunately, I can't share the exact code because we have a wrapper over Google Maps and that code here would make no sense.

Another thing I ensured was not to place any marker on the map until I have already sorted according to the `waypoint_order Array`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for get way points, this code working properly

```
var rleg = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0];

// get way points from route
var w = [], wp;
wp = rleg.via_waypoints
for (var i = 0; i < wp.length; i++) {
    w[i] = {
    lat : wp[i].lat().toFixed(6),
    lng : wp[i].lng().toFixed(6)
 };
}
if (w.length !== 0) {
   route.wayPoints = JSON.stringify(w);
} else {
   console.log("no way points");
}
```