# Need to get waypoint_order after optimizedwaypoint

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var something;

var locations = <?php echo json_encode($googlemaparray);?>;
var uniquelocations= <?php echo json_encode($uniquegoogle);?>;
var barinfo = <?php echo json_encode($barinfoarray);?>;
var marker, i;
var total = uniquelocations.length;
var test;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0],locations[1]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(uniquelocations[0],uniquelocations[1]);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(uniquelocations[0],uniquelocations[1]);
var waypts = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < uniquelocations.length; i+=2){
        waypts.push({
        location:new google.maps.LatLng(uniquelocations[i],uniquelocations[i+1])});
    };
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints:waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints:true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
};
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var something=response.routes.waypoint_order;
        console.log(something);
    }   
});
//  test = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween({
//  from:new google.maps.LatLng(uniquelocations[0],uniquelocations[1]),
//  to:new google.maps.LatLng(uniquelocations[2],uniquelocations[3])
//  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

How do I gain access to the array from waypoint_order, because I need to know how my waypoints are being ordered. When I console.log(something) for the existing code, it says "undefined" in the console. I am using a WAMP stack to test this code out.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: related question: [Google Directions API return different waypoint_order and legs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433069/google-directions-api-return-different-waypoint-order-and-legs)

Answer (score 1):

The waypoints order is `response.routes[0].waypoint_order` (where 0 is the first route if more than one are returned).